# How to get past the old man in Viridian City in Pokemon Leaf Green?

Tags: pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

It's been a while since I last played [Pokémon Leaf green](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_FireRed_and_LeafGreen_Versions).
I am playing it with my nephew and he asked me how to get to first Gym (Brock) to get the Boulder badge.

Here is the problem:

[image: An old man]

An old man is lying there and not allowing us to pass through to the path that leads to the gym. As we are in a hurry (I can neither recall nor [find any good source](http://www.pokemondungeon.net/firered-and-leafgreen/walkthrough/boulder-badge.php)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply enough, you're not supposed to leave Viridian City yet, as you haven't done everything you were asked to do. Go into the PokéMart and you'll be given a task to return to Pallet Town, then it should be simple from there.

Answer (score -1):

Go into the Viridian City PokéMart and retrieve Prof. Oak's parcel. Deliver the parcel to Oak in Pallet Town.

Once you do this, the old man will stand up.